# Is it possible to have same element name for multiple classes in JAXB?

Tags: xml, jaxb

I am working with JAXB marshal and unmarshal . I have following scenario where I have to use same name(Person.ELEMENT_NAME) for 2 `@XmlRootElement` .

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Person{

    public final static String ELEMENT_NAME = "person";

    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String title;
    //Getter Setter
}

@XmlRootElement(name = Person.ELEMENT_NAME)
public class ReceiverPerson extends Person {
    @XmlElement
    private String gender;
    //Getter Setter 
}

@XmlRootElement(name = Person.ELEMENT_NAME)
public class SenderPerson extends Person {
    @XmlElement
    private String age;
    //Getter Setter 
}
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Human {

    @XmlElement(name = Person.ELEMENT_NAME , type = ReceiverPerson.class)
    private ReceiverPerson rP;
    @XmlElement(name = Person.ELEMENT_NAME , type= SenderPerson.class)
    private SenderPerson sP;
    @XmlElement
    private String type;

    @XmlAnyElement
    private List<Object> unknown;

     //Getter Setter
}

public class Test{
 public static void main(String[] args){

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Human.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    Human human2,human1;
    String humans = "This xml is writtem after my code , because its too big";
    human1 = new Human();
    human1.setType("Human");
    SenderPerson sp = new SenderPerson();
    sp.setAge("23");
    sp.setName("Marry");
    sp.setTitle("Lecturer");
    ReceiverPerson rP = new ReceiverPerson();
    rP.setName("John");
    rP.setTitle("Professor");
    rP.setGender("Male");


    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(human1, sw);
    System.out.println("Marshalling by creating a Human object");
    System.out.println(sw.toString());



    human2 = (Human) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(sw.toString()));
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(human2, sw);
    System.out.println("Marshalling from my own xml");
    System.out.println(sw.toString());

}
}
```

The String humans in Test class has following xml:

```
<human>
<type>Human Being</type>
<person type="ReceiverPerson">
<name>John</name>
<title>Professor</title>
<gender>Male</gender>
</person>
<person type="SenderPerson">
<name>Marry</name>
<title>Lecturer</title>
<age>23</age>
</person>
<anything>I am unknown to the xml</anything>
</human>
```

I don't know what's going on but i get following output :

```
Marshalling by creating a Human object
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<human>
    <type>Human</type>
</human>

Marshalling from my own xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<human>
    <type>Human</type>
</human>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<human>
    <person>
        <name>Marry</name>
        <title>Lecturer</title>
    </person>
    <type>Human Being</type>
    <anything>I am unknown to the xml</anything>
</human>
```

Sorry for the big examples , my questions are as follows

1. Why is the first output missing the persons ?
2. Why is the second output missing the `age` ?
3. Why is the second output missing the whole person for ReceiverElement (The description for John)?
4. Why is there two `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` in my second output ?
5. Is it possible to have something like `<person type="ReceiverPerson">` in the xml's by using the `@XmlElement(name = Person.ELEMENT_NAME , type = ReceiverPerson.class)` or in any other way ?
6. The output of the last paragraph (unmarshall the produced xml and then marshal) does not give the proper output , the output is like :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <human>
   <person>
       <name>Marry</name>
       <title>Lecturer</title>
   </person>
   <type>Human</type>
   </human>
   ```

For some reason the Person subclasses are not being generated . Any idea please ?

Thanks in advance for anyone who has atleast read this lengthy question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - Why is the first output missing the persons ?

You are missing the following calls:

```
   human1.setsP(sp);
   human1.setrP(rP);
```

> 2 - Why is the second output missing the age ?

Once you fix item 1 you get `age` in the second output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<human>
    <person>
        <name>John</name>
        <title>Professor</title>
        <gender>Male</gender>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Marry</name>
        <title>Lecturer</title>
        <age>23</age>
    </person>
    <type>Human</type>
</human>
```

> 3 - Why is the second output missing the whole person for
>   ReceiverElement (The description for John)?

Once you fix item 1 this will work.

> 4 - Why is there two  in my second output ?

I don't see that you are getting this declaration twice.  I don't see it twice when I run your demo code.

> 5 - Is it possible to have something like  in the xml's by using the @XmlElement(name =
>   Person.ELEMENT_NAME , type = ReceiverPerson.class) or in any other way
>   ?

Since your properties are typed at the subclass level you don't need any sort of type qualifier.  When a type qualifier is necessary JAXB will leverage the `xsi:type` attribute.  You may find the following interesting:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

Comment: Hi Blaise , thank you so much . I have edited my question a bit , can you have a look at it , please ?